# Find users in mongodb based on distance with geospatial query

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query

I am working on some project in which I have to find some users of one particular region, like greater than 20 km and less than 40 km, for which I have written query

```
query.location = {
  $nearSphere: 
  {
    $geometry: 
    {
      type:'Point',
      coordinates: 
      [
        bookingData.bookingAddress.location.coordinates[0],
        bookingData.bookingAddress.location.coordinates[1]
      ]
    },
    $minDistance: (20*1000),
    $maxDistance: (40*1000)  // this distance should be in meters (in our case I have set 40 km)
  }
};
```

But the result doesn't show anything, even if I have the users of that latitude and longitude in my database.

When I run query

```
query.location = {
  $nearSphere:
  {
    $geometry:
    {
      type:'Point',
      coordinates:
      [
        bookingData.bookingAddress.location.coordinates[0],
        bookingData.bookingAddress.location.coordinates[1]
      ]
    },
    $maxDistance: (40*1000)  // this distance should be in meters (in our case I have set 40 km)
  }
};
```

it shows correct result.

This is the model I have made for storing location :

```
bookingAddress : {
        location : {
            'type':{type:String,enum:CONST.GEO_JSON_TYPES.Point,default: CONST.GEO_JSON_TYPES.Point},
            coordinates: {type: [Number], default: [0, 0],required: true}
        },
        address : {type : String,default:null}
    },
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: could you provide structure of documents in your collection and expected result for them?

Comment: can you make sure your mongodb version is at least 2.6. the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) says $minDistance requires 2.6 or newer. I tried at version 2.4.9 and $minDistance is simply ignored.

Comment: i am using mongodb version greater than 2.6